# Requesting help editing a formula in a TM1 worksheet

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, cognos-tm1

The said TM1 worksheet uses the DBRW formula to write values that users enter, to a cube, and also uses the same to fetch the value and display it in the worksheet. The values in the cube consist of movie codes such as 7500023. This movie code can be mapped to a movie title in a dimension DIM. It is to be noted that this movie code and the movie title are both aliases of the principal name used in the dimension, which runs along like 0007500023 (The movie code with zeroes preceding). I'd like the movie titles to be displayed in the worksheet instead of the movie codes.

I tried using the SUBNM function, but it opens up a subset editor and also doesn't write values to the cube like DBRW. So, that's ruled out.

The DBRA function seemed perfect when it came to fetching the movie titles from the dimension DIM. But this doesn't write the values to the cube.

Is there any way I can combine the DBRA and the DBRW function in a formula or is there an alternative function for this purpose?

Comment: I came up with a formula that integrates the DBRA and DBRW formula, but I'm stuck with a circular reference which seems nigh impossible to break out of. =IF(LEN($D$25)=12,DBRW($D$6,pVersion,pPO,D$20,$C25,$E$17),DBRA(pServer&":MPM_Product",$D$25,"Name"))

Comment: It's necessary that I have to refer to the current cell $D$25 in the DBRA function. The above formula should be checking if the length of the current cell is 12 in which case the cell value needs to be written back to the cube in TM1. If otherwise, the value in the current cell has to be used as a reference in fetching the alias of the element that forms the said value in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add an extra column which will extract the alias = DBRA.
And then I will base your IF statement on the new column.

Otherwise, if you don't need the code, then why not use the alias in the first place? Export data with the alias on. Then you don't even need to retrieve the alias, because it's already there.

It just doesn't make sense to put them both in one formula.
When you recalculate - excel assess the formula once.
But you're expecting it to assess it multiple times. (hence the circular reference)

Comment: Thanks Gemmo,

I didn't need both functions in the same formula after all! :)